# Montar DataTables com Repeater

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-datatables

Estou montando uma `DataTables jQuery` com repeater `ASP.NET C#`.
O que estou fazendo de errado?

Tenho usado o código.

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptMeusDados" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable" role="grid">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>IDCAL</th>
                                <th>IDVerificacao</th>
                                <th>Pergunta</th>
                                <th>IDVerificacaoCliente</th>
                                <th>Alterar</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IDCAL")%></td>
                            <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IDVerificacao")%></td>
                            <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Pergunta")%></td>
                            <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IDVerificacaoCliente")%></td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"> linkButton</asp:LinkButton></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="DataTables-1.10.0/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="DataTables-1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="DataTables-1.10.0/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="DataTables-1.10.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var table = $('#example').DataTable(
                         {
                             "columnDefs": [
                         {
                             "targets": [4],
                             "orderable": false,
                             "searchable": false,
                             "sortable": false
                         }
                             ],
                             "lengthMenu": [[10, 20, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "Tudo"]],
                             "language": {
                                 "zeroRecords": 'Nada foi encontrado',
                                 "search": 'Buscar:',
                                 "processing": 'Processando...',
                                 "paginate": {
                                     "next": 'Próxima',
                                     "previous": 'Anterior'
                                 },
                                 "lengthMenu": '_MENU_ linhas por página.',
                                 "info": 'Página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_',
                                 "infoFiltered": '(Filtrando a parti de entradas totais _MAX_)'
                             }



                         });

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Alguma ideia de como resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tiago muito obrigado pela resposta,

Meu problema não era a sintaxe,

Descobri que o visual studio novo estava com muito erro, por estar em fase de testes ainda. Mais descobrir que o codigo abaixo funciona perfeitamente.

Segue o código.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMeusDados" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table id="example" class="cell-border">
                <thead>
                    <tr style="background-color: #748455;">
                        <th>
                            CalculoPrazo
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Prazo
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            IDAcao
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            IDVerificacao
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            IDCAL
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            IDCALCliente
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Descricao
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Acao
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            IDVerificacaoCliente
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            OcultarReagendamento
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            StatusVerificacao
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Pergunta
                        </th>
                        <th>
                        </th>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr style="background: #FFFFFF;">
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbGrupoPrazo" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CalculoPrazo") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbPrazo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Prazo") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbIDAcao" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IDAcao") %>' Visible="false" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbIDVerificacao" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IDVerificacao") %>'
                        Visible="false" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbIDCAL" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IDCAL") %>' Visible="false" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbIDCALCliente" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IDCALCliente") %>'
                        Visible="false" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbCalCliente" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Descricao") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbAcao" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Acao") %>' Visible="false" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbIDVerificacaoCliente" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IDVerificacaoCliente") %>'
                        Visible="false" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbOcultarReagendamento" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OcultarReagendamento") %>'
                        Visible="false" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbStatusVerificacao" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StatusVerificacao") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbVerificacao" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Pergunta") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="lbAlterar_Click">[Alterar]</asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" OnClick="lbConclui_Click" Style="float: left">[Concluir]</asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="js/modal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').dataTable({
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 20, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "Tudo"]],
            "language": {
                "zeroRecords": 'Nada foi encontrado',
                "search": 'Buscar:',
                "processing": 'Processando...',
                "paginate": {
                    "next": 'Próxima',
                    "previous": 'Anterior'
                },
                "lengthMenu": '_MENU_ linhas por página.',
                "info": 'Página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_',
                "infoFiltered": '(Filtrado a parti de _MAX_ entradas totais)',
                "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 de 0 de 0 entradas."
            },
            "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [12, 13],
                "orderable": false,
                "searchable": false
            },
            {
                "targets": [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9],
                "visible": false
            }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Você está muito preso à sintaxe do componente. Isso pode ser resolvido com um link simples.

Ao invés de

```
<td>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"> linkButton</asp:LinkButton>
</td>
```

Use:

```
<td>
    <a href="edita.aspx?id=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IDCAL")%>">Editar</a>
</td>
```

Nesse caso, estou supondo que `IDCAL` é o ID pelo qual você pesquisará o item a ser editado, nessa suposta página `edita.aspx`.